# Does anyone know how to combine 6 similar Excel formulas together?

Tags: microsoft-excel

They all work fine on their own but I need them to all be as one. Is this possible?

```
=IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A2,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!$A$2:$C$11,2,0))
=IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A14,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$14:C$23,2,0))
=IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A26,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$26:C$35,2,0))
=IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A38,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$47:C$47,2,0))
=IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A49,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$49:C$59,2,0))
=IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A61,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$61:C$74,2,0))
```

Comment: What is your rule behind those formulas? Can you please post some sample data and explain what output should be? How you've tried to combine them? What was the problem? Maybe google for "nested IF Excel".

Comment: i apologise, i am not very good on excel.
basically what i am trying to do is pull data from another sheet but the data that i pull through depends on what is says in J22 and also V22.
 depending on what J22 is ie 150 then i have a separate table for 150 so it's first option will to look at j22 then go to the correct table then look for v22 and send back the figure this refers to, does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggests, you should learn how to do NESTED IFs.

But here is what you are probably after:

> =IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A2,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!$A$2:$C$11,2,0),IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A14,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$14:C$23,2,0),IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A26,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$26:C$35,2,0),IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A38,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$47:C$47,2,0),IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A49,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$49:C$59,2,0),IF(J22='Storm L+P '!A61,VLOOKUP(V22,'Storm L+P '!A$61:C$74,2,0),"J22 does not match any of the criteria"))))))

I have inserted `"J22 does not match any of the criteria"` you can replace this for whatever you wish to display in the even that CELL `J22` doesn't match any of the given CELLs from sheet `'Storm L+P'`

Comment: hello peter, thank you for you response, it comes back with a blank cell

Comment: hello, apologies, when i copy the formula to my sheet it says we have found a typo do you want to accept this correction, if i click yes it then put * infront of each IF and then throws back black cells

Comment: Hi @dan try now I had forgot some commas in the formula

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern and INDEX to return the correct range to the VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(v22,INDEX('Storm L+P '!$A:$A,MATCH(J2,'Storm L+P '!$A:$A,0)):INDEX('Storm L+P '!$C:$C,MATCH(J2,'Storm L+P '!$A:$A,0)+10),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I was thinking of something along these lines, also.  But  notice that the OP's last IF doesn't involve a range of 10.